# Referring system views and functions in production functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, dmv

I am using the following system objects in a stored procedure in order to build dynamic `T-SQL` statements:

- `[sys].[objects]`
- `[sys].[parameters]`
- `[sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set]`
- `[sys].[columns]`

As I have never used system objects in production code I am wondering are there any drawbacks or issues that could appear (for example concerning performance) or it is `OK` to use them as regular user defined objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no real performance problems related to using the system objects to build your T-SQL.

Consider also that building your dynamic T-SQL is probably a much lighter load on your server than actually running the T-SQL statements that you generate.

There are also INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, but these only partially cover the system objects.  I mention this only to warn you that, although once recommended, it has many limitations and I do not use them any more.

Likely the biggest issue for your code is that system objects *do change over time*.  Probably most changes would not affect your code generation, but you should plan in advance before upgrading to a new version of SQL Server.

SQL Server documentation usually details out the changes for the next upgrade.

For example, here is a link for SQL Server 2014's **breaking changes**.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx#SQL14

Comment: Another note is that usage of system objects prevent views, functions etc. from using `WITH SCHEMABINDING`, which can have trickle-down effects.  Probably not overly relevant in the OP's use case of code generation, but more for other scenarios used by readers who might stumble across this question (e.g. using `sys.all_objects` for sequence generation).